# Testing datepicker gem with Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, datepicker, capybara

I am using the bootstrap-datepicker-rails gem for my app and have created a form where users can pick a start date and an end date.

When the user edits the form I want them to be able to see the dates that they had previously chosen. (e.g. Start: October 31, 2015, End: November 15, 2015).

I am trying to write a test to make sure my app does this, but I'm stuck on the syntax.

**user_updates_project_spec.rb**

```
require "rails_helper"

feature "User updates project" do
   before (:each) do
      @user = create(:user)
      login_as(@user, scope: :user)
      @project = create(:project, creator: @user,
                  name: "Building a robot",
                  start_at: "2015-10-31",
                  end_at: "2015-11-15", )
   end

  scenario "and sees correct dates on form" do
     visit edit_user_project_path(@user, @project)

     expect(".datepicker").to have_content("October 31, 2015")
   end
end
```

The error I get is:

```
Failure/Error: expect(".datepicker").to have_content("October 31, 2015")
  expected to find text "October 31, 2015" in ".datepicker"
```

This is what my form looks like:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 pl0">
   <%= f.input :start_at, label: "Start Date", as: :string,
                  input_html: {value:@project.set_start_date_for_form.to_s(:long),
                  class: "datepicker start-date"} %>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 pr0">
   <%= f.input :end_at, label: "End Date", as: :string,
                  input_html: {value: @project.set_end_date_for_form.to_s(:long),
                  class: "datepicker end-date"} %>
</div>
```

Any ideas on why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

The way you've written your expects, what you're really saying is expect the string ".datepicker" to have the content "October 31, 2015" which is never going to be true.  expect needs to take an element that the have_content matcher can be run against rather than a string.  You could rewrite it like this

```
expect(page.find(:css, '.datepicker.start-date')).to have_content("October 31, 2015")
```

although a better method would probably be to use

```
expect(page).to have_css('.datepicker', text: 'October 31, 2015)
```

since that will match if the content is changing or being loaded via ajax.
One other thing to note is that since you're using a datepicker widget you might actually need to look at the html that is produced by the JS in a real browser, instead of the html in your view tempalte, to determine exactly which element you need to be checking for the content inside.

Comment: You were right, I wasn't checking inside the correct element. 
What ended up working was: 

    expect(page).to have_css("#project_start_at[value='October 31, 2015']")
    expect(page).to have_css("#project_end_at[value='November 15, 2015']")

Comment: Ok -- since you're checking for value attributes on the two elements I'm going to assume they are input fields of some type - in that case you could also use expect(page).to have_field('project_start_at', with: 'October 31, 2015')  which provides a bit better read and a few other features

Answer (score 0):

I guess there may be a confusing for `.start-date` and `.end-date` also you can use `.text` attribute to check them:

```
expect(page.find(:css, '.datepicker.start-date').text).to eq('October 31, 2015')
expect(page.find(:css, '.datepicker.end-date').text).to eq('November 15, 2015')
```

If it fails, you can print the value to debug it:

```
puts page.find(:css, '.datepicker.start-date').text
```

Comment: It almost worked.  Now I get the following error: 
User updates project and sees correct dates on form
     Failure/Error: expect(page.find(:css, '.datepicker.start-date').text).to eq('October 31, 2015')

       expected: "October 31, 2015"
            got: ""

       (compared using ==)

It seems like it's not detecting the input value. When I actually go the edit page everything works like it should. I just can't test it.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I wasn't checking inside the correct element when testing.

What solved it was:

```
expect(page).to have_css("#project_start_at[value='October 31, 2015']")
expect(page).to have_css("#project_end_at[value='November 15, 2015']")
```

The element id's that datepicker set were project_start_at and project_end_at.